# calling particular textview means the retrieve data is not displayed on emulator

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-emulator

I have tried to develop retrieving the count value from soap webservices and display them  to android emulator. Here I have mentioned particular textview means it is not display on my emulator. Why this is not display on my emulator. Please help me. Which line I have to change.
This is my android code:

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/data";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "data";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/XcartLogin/services/RetailerWs?wsdl";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.retrieve);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");//Result string will split & store in an array
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       // TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        for(int i = 0; i<resultArr.length;i++){
        tv.append(resultArr[i]+"\n\n");
       }
        setContentView(tv);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   }
```

Here i have to wrote TextView tv = new TextView(this); line means the output is displayed.but i have to put dis line   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); means the output is not display on my emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line  `setContentView(tv);`. I don't seem to find it correct to use two `setContentView()` here.

Because you have already called the  `setContentView(R.layout.retrieve);` in the first place and you have initialized your TextView here,

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

So,

```
tv.append(resultArr[i]+"\n\n");
```

alone should work. No need to set `tv` again.

**EDIT 1**

Your TextView in xml should be something like this,.

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Remove other attributes,.

Comment: ya it is correct.the output is displayed.but the output is display with string name.dis is my output.Hello World, AndroidLoginExampleActivity!3.but i wish to display 3 only.

Comment: Its because in your retrieve.xml you could have used andorid:text attribute for your TextView. Remove it from there. Since you are using append method it will add the out put with the text which you have set from the xml. That's the problem. Nothing else

Comment: Thanks...thank u so much...it is very helpful for me.then i learned some basic information also here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `append` does.

You can write

```
   String s = ""
    for(int i = 0; i<resultArr.length;i++) {
            s += resultArr[i]+"\n\n";
    }
    tv.setText(s)
```

Better use `StringBuilder` but above should work